# Troubleshooting Payment Generation Issue with WooCommerce Subscription Plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I added the WooCommerce subscription plugin to my WordPress about 20 days ago. It was working fine until Friday, but when it was Monday, I tried to generate a subscription payment using Asaas. However, while I can generate a product order, I can't generate a subscription order. An error message appears saying, "An error occurred while completing the payment, please contact us."

Could you assist me?
(I didn't purchase the official WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin; I found the file from a download. Is it possible that it's been blocked?)

My friend installed it in his project, and it's working fine.
I've tried creating a new project, resetting the database, and still no luck.

Comment: Hey brow, Actualy the pluggin 'Asas' was with problem, than i update it and fixed!

Comment: Please, you should better delete this question as this issue is something very basic, not really useful and not related to coding.

Answer (score 0):

The pluggin Asaas Payment should be update, so i do and the promem was solved